# Urban Airship - Channel id is null for reinstallation of same apk

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using Urban Airship for push notifications in Android. I am getting channel id for the first installation, but when after reinstall of the same apk, the channel id is null. And this was happening sometimes. Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The Channel ID takes a http call to create, so it will not be available right away. If your device has limited connectivity it may take a while for the channel to create.

Your application can be notified when the channel is created by using a broadcast receiver - http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html#listening-for-push-events